# Avoid literal repetition

Tags: regex

Suppose I have this string:

```
Address XXXXX city XXXXX
```

And this regEX:

```
Address (.*?) city (.*?)
```

What will happen if the Address is "The city of London" ?

Comment: Try it.. But the regex should match `Address Downing Street city The city of London` properly, because you made the captures "non-greedy".

Comment: OTOH, This won't work I think: `Address 25 city hall city new york`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to regular expressions. Yes can try. But I know what would happen and imagine..What is a better REGEX to achieve this without errors ?

Comment: How do you get the string mentioned above? have you created it yourself? could be quite easy if you use something like $Address and $city instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your reex engine is in greedy mode or not.

If it's in greedy mode, it will work as expected since it will look for the longest match.

Whether your particular regex engines runs in greedy mode by default, or whether it even *has* a greedy mode, is not something we can tell you based on the information provided in the question.

If you're using .NET, [this page](http://www.tipsntracks.com/180/using-regular-expressions-metacharacters-with-net-greedy-and-lazy-quantifier.html) has a description on greedy versus lazy matching.

Basically, given the string `XYZZY`, the regex `X.*Y` will match `XYZZY` (greedy) while `X.*?Y` will match `XY` (lazy).

What you need is a way to ensure you can differentiate between the delimiters and the elements of your string, otherwise you'll be in trouble no matter what, such as with:

```
Address The city baths city Manchester city, England
```

Perhaps you could look into something like:

```
Address "put address here" city "put city here"
```

and try to make sure you never get a city name with quotes in it. However, be careful. I once worked on a project where we managed to get some decent compression on city names (it was embedded so every byte counted) by only having to store alpha characters.

Shortly thereafter, we rolled out nationally and the residents of `A1 mining settlement` were rather miffed at our short-sightedness :-) One town in the whole of Oz with a digit in the name, who'd have thought?

Alternatively, put the address and city on separate lines thus:

```
Address: The city baths
City:    Manchester city, England
```

Then you can look for things like:

```
^Address:\s*(.*)$
^City:\s*(.*)$
```

Comment: I use .NET .. What is greedy mode ?

Comment: The question mark after * should put it into non-greedy mode.

Comment: And regardless of greedy mode, I think you can construct cases that will fail to parse either way. "city" is a bad delimiter as it could appear in both of the tokens.